# Pure css slider - why are images shown in block?

Tags: html, css

I have an image slider-everything worked fine when I only had 4 images. When I started adding images to the slide show, 2 pictures are being shown at the same time so the slider doesn't work.

I would appreciate any ideas on what I did wrong when I added images.

Thank you!

```css
html {
  background: radial-gradient(#238dbb, #114476);
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #134c7e;
}
input.set {
  display: none;
}
#slide1:checked ~ .mask .overflow {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#slide2:checked ~ .mask .overflow {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
#slide3:checked ~ .mask .overflow {
  margin-left: -200%;
}
#slide4:checked ~ .mask .overflow {
  margin-left: -300%;
}
#slide5:checked ~ .mask .overflow {
  margin-left: -400%;
}
#slides {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
}
#slides .mask {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}
#slides .overflow {
  width: 400%;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
#slides .slide {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
}
#controls {
  width: 100%;
}
#controls label {
  display: none;
  width: 5%;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
}
#controls label:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4),
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5) {
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#slide5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4) {
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="slides">

  <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" class="set" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" class="set" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3" class="set" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4" class="set" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide5" class="set" />

  <div class="mask">

    <div class="overflow">

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/phuket/portals/phuket-com/homepage/phuket-magazine/freedom-beach/pagePropertiesImage/freedom-beach.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">2</div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/phuket/portals/phuket-com/homepage/phuket-magazine/freedom-beach/pagePropertiesImage/freedom-beach.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/33/6882876-beach-sunset.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/rt17YTU.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="controls" onclick="">

    <label for="slide1"></label>
    <label for="slide2"></label>
    <label for="slide3"></label>
    <label for="slide4"></label>
    <label for="slide5"></label>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In taking a look at your CSS, your `.slide` class has `width: 25%`. Of course, you'll exceed the parent container's width if you have 5 slides at 25% width. The last slide will wrap underneath, which is likely why you're seeing two.

Try changing your `.slide` class to be `width: 20%` instead so that the sum of their widths is 100%.

So that they still occupy 100% width each, you'll have to set the parent `.overflow` width to be `500%` (100% for each slide).

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt the width of `#slides .overflow` Now it has `width: 400%;`, which allows 4 fullwidth children. If you add slides, increase that value, for example 600% for 6 slides that each are 100% of the `.mask` container width.

Also the width of the `#slides .slide` elements needs to be adapted, like 16.6666%  in case of 6 slides. (i.e. one sixth ot the container)

Comment: If you have five children of `width: 25%`, that means they will be 125% the width of their parent. Won't they wrap regardless of the parent's width? [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4m94e5gm/1/)